# Converting ASCII to HEX with padding and back?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am working in a database that requires ASCII values to be stored as hex with spacing between each character. I've found a way to do the 'encryption/decryption' in Python, but I need to be able to do it natively in SQL 2008 R2. Is this even possible?

Sample input/output below:

```
Text Input:                        Test
Input in ASCII:                    0x54657374
How input needs to be in database: 0x540065007007400
```

I have no clue how to convert from the text input to the database-required input and back strictly in SQL. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it matter what datatype the input in ASCII is?

Comment: The input hex string will be VARBINARY(128)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are okay to save the input in ASCII as a nchar, here is one way:

```
declare @myHex nchar(12)
set @myHex = '0x54657374'
select '0x' +
       SUBSTRING(@myHex, 3, 2) + '00' +
       SUBSTRING(@myHex, 5, 2) + '00' +
       SUBSTRING(@myHex, 7, 2) + '00' +
       SUBSTRING(@myHex, 9, 2) + '00'
```

Comment: Does this account for a variable-sized ASCII string?

Comment: @AlbertDorson it should. ASCII string should be 10 characters long as far as I know. Can you give an example of what you mean by, "variable-sized ASCII string"?

Comment: Here's the interesting part..The software I'm using encodes each character to its Hex representation (P = 50, etc), adds a spacer of 00 between each character (along with a following 00), and throws that into the database.

So, if I have a string PartitionTest, it's stored in the database as 0x50006100720074006900740069006F006E005400650073007400.

I THINK I have the code down to remove all of the 00s leaving me with 0x506172746974696F6E54657374, but I need to decode that back into PartitionTest. In the end I need to be able to convert from string to padded hex string and back

Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertDorson will the hex string be always of the same length (e.g. 28 characters in your example)?

Comment: No, the string varies greatly as the input could be PartitionTest::05011:000 etc etc etc. I do not know of a limit for this string. The field is listed as VARBINARY(128) so I assume it can't take over 128 chars of input.

Comment: Could this be done as simply as `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(128),0x506172746974696F6E546573743A3A303530313030)`? Or is there something wrong with this way of doing it?

Comment: @AlbertDorson you could do that, but that would result in the conversion of your hexadecimal value to its corresponding ASCII value. Which is "PartitionTest::050100". Is that what you want?